# How to pass arguments to the CMake build of a plugin from gradle build in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, cmake

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42715120/9142279) one, except that in that question, he wanted to pass arguments directly from gradle to CMake. But in my case, I am not directly invoking the cmake build, but rather "flutter is doing it for me"

So to put it all together, when the app build starts:

- gradle build of the app starts (`build.gradle` in the flutter project) ------(1)
- the above build invokes gradle build of the plugin (`build.gradle` in the plugin's project) ------(2)
- the gradle build of the plugin invokes the CMake build of the plugin (`CMakeLists.txt` in the plugin project) ------(3)

Now sending args from step (2) to step (3) is as mentioned in the link above.

My question is how to send args from step (1) to step (2)?

I am not very experienced with gradle but I tried inspecting the `build.gradle` file of step (1) to see from where it is invoking the `build.gradle` of the plugin, but I wasn't able to do that.

### Update:

- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70013088/9142279) answer is very similar to what I want, except that, as I mentioned, I want to pass variable from a gradle build that indirectly invokes cmake.
- The use case for me is as follows: the plugin has some C code and uses shared libraries, these libraries have different versions and the user must choose one of them at build time, thats why I want the user to pass variables to cmake, for ex:

```
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DLIB_VERSION=VERSION_WITH_SOME_OPTION"
            }
        }
```

and then in CMake:

```
if(${LIB_VERSION})
# link some version of the shared libs
else()
# link another version
```

Comment: Please update the question with a use case. Plugins should, where possible, be self-contained so that they are re-usable. What are the circumstances where an application developer would want to tweak how a dependant plugin is built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution, but I don't know if this is the right way to do it, as it defines the variables to be passed as "global gradle variables".

So we have 3 files:

(1) `android/app/build.gradle` in the flutter app's project folder

(2) `android/build.gradle` in the plugin's project folder

(3) `CMakeLists.txt` in the plugin's project folder

We want to pass an argument from (1) to (3) (since the user of the plugin only has access to (1)):

- in (1), define the variables to be passed, put this at the end of the file:

```
ext {
    Q16 = 1
    HDRI = 0
}
```

- in (2), read the variables at the beginning of the file:

```
def Q8
def Q16
def HDRI
if(rootProject.hasProperty("Q8")){
    Q8 = 1
}
else{
    Q8 = 0
}
if(rootProject.hasProperty("Q16")){
    Q16 = 1
}
else{
    Q16 = 0
}
if(rootProject.hasProperty("HDRI")){
    HDRI = 1
}
else{
    HDRI = 0
}
```

Then pass them to (3) (since (2) directly invokes (3)):

```
   android{
    ...
    defaultConfig{
        ...
        externalNativeBuild{
            cmake {
                arguments "-DQ8=${Q8}" , "-DQ16=${Q16}" , "-DHDRI=${HDRI}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Now we can read them in (3):

```
    message("from CMakeLists.txt: Q8 = ${Q8}")
    message("from CMakeLists.txt: Q16 = ${Q16}")
    message("from CMakeLists.txt: HDRI = ${HDRI}")
```